# login and logout in several laravel projects

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

good morning. I have several domains and subdomains with Laravel. One of the subdomains does the login, logout and verification tasks.
My question is, how can I log in to the rest of the subdomain that I log in?
The bigger problem I have is that it does not log in to the site but it runs online?
And that I send a request, it is sent, but the answer does not come for Ajax to show, but it comes in the network
thanks.

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Does logging into one subdomain grant access to all other subdomains or do they all act like separate systems using the same database?

Comment: @IGP all subdomain use one database for user ,

Comment: @IGP i want  login in subdomain or domain and logedin  other domains and subdomain (.domain.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a database table that checks the user logins that will also expire. So when a user enters your sub domains it checks via ip(not recommended) or other things if that user is logged in.

Comment: This solution also came to my mind, through a cookie, but the request that is sent is verified and logged in, for example, the user table is updated, but the cookie is not set and the user does not log in, and there is another problem that I can not log in to the project